# Ruby Code Autoindentation in Vim

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation

I have copied a Ruby example into Vim, but it turns out that this messed up the indentation.
I tried to make Vim apply the Ruby specific indentation. To do that I uncommented the following lines in the global vimrc file:

```
if has ("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif
```

And pressed `gg=G` in Vim. Now it changes some of the indentation, but it still has some errors:

- Class definitions don't get indented.
- Comments don't get indented and remain at the start of the lines.

Comment: Good question. I've always resorted to using ":r!pbpaste" to insert from the clipboard on osx b/c of this issue.

Comment: The Ruby indent file probably needs tweaking. Sounds like an opportunity for you to contribute to the Vim community! :-) Look for the `ruby.vim` file in the Vim `indent` directory.

Comment: It does sound like the Ruby indent file isn't perfect.  You can read Vim help at `:h indent-expression` for a start on understanding how to modify the ruby.vim file.  Also, look through the other language files in the indent directory to see examples of how to things.

Answer (score 1):

Before paste from outer source, use this command

`:set paste`

then enter to insert mode and paste.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem the OP is talking about in the bullets.